# Line numbers in juypyter

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting used to IP Notebook and jupyter, and I wonder what the function of the line numbers is. They always seem to end up scrambled, and I don't know if they can be reset. Are they the equivalent of the command prompt (`>>>`)? Can they be safely ignored? Do they interfere if you run python on PyCharms and show up there after a `.py` file built with IP Notebook is saved as such?

[image]

Comment: They show execution order of the cells, they get renumbered when you rerun the code in the cell.

Answer (score 2):

They're not really line numbers, they're execution count numbers. The first cell you execute gets number 1, the second 2 and so on. If you then re-execute the first cell it would get number 3.

If it is a cell that takes a while to execute, you'll see an asterisk [`*`].

In my experience, they serve no real practical purpose other than to indicate the order of execution. They can be reset when you restart the kernel.

Edit: To answer your other questions: I think you can safely ignore them. If you use file>download as>python the resulting file will have these numbers as comments, so they will not serve a practical purpose.

Comment: I went to `cmd` and quit (`Ctrl + C`), and proceeded to go back to IP Notebook through `cmd`. Clicked on the `.ipynb`, and the `[]` count numbers had not reset. What do you mean by restarting the kernel?

Comment: Using the method you described, the old execution order numbers will still be there, but if you execute a cell it will restart the numbering and show `In [1]` upon sucessful execution. If you want to clear all of the numbering, go to the "Kernel" drop down menu, click on "Restart" and then select the red button that says "Clear all outputs & restart".